# Resource file (.resx) in Visual Studio 2017 "value cannot be displayed" error

Tags: visual-studio-2017, resx

I created a resource file for localization in Visual Studio 2017. Every time I set a value in value field VS crashes.

[image]

This is the code of the resx file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
    <xsd:schema id="root" xmlns="" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
        <xsd:element name="root" msdata:IsDataSet="true">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xsd:element name="data">
                        <xsd:complexType>
                            <xsd:sequence>
                                <xsd:element name="value" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="1" />
                                <xsd:element name="comment" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="2" />
                            </xsd:sequence>
                            <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" msdata:Ordinal="1" />
                            <xsd:attribute name="type" type="xsd:string" msdata:Ordinal="3" />
                            <xsd:attribute name="mimetype" type="xsd:string" msdata:Ordinal="4" />
                        </xsd:complexType>
                    </xsd:element>
                    <xsd:element name="resheader">
                        <xsd:complexType>
                            <xsd:sequence>
                                <xsd:element name="value" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="1" />
                            </xsd:sequence>
                            <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" use="required" />
                        </xsd:complexType>
                    </xsd:element>
                </xsd:choice>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
    </xsd:schema>
    <resheader name="resmimetype">
        <value>text/microsoft-resx</value>
    </resheader>
    <resheader name="version">
        <value>1.3</value>
    </resheader>
    <resheader name="reader">
        <value>System.Resources.ResXResourceReader, System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.3500.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</value>
    </resheader>
    <resheader name="writer">
        <value>System.Resources.ResXResourceWriter, System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.3500.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</value>
    </resheader>
</root>
```

Is this a bug or should I change anything in the format of the file?

Comment: Right click on the resx file in Solution Explorer > Open With ... > choose XML (text) Editor > OK. Copy content of this file here.

Comment: I posted the resx code @Misaz

Comment: How old is the file? Was it created in Visual Studio or in another app? What Visual Studio version was it created in? Visual Studio 2017 is using structure of version 2.0 (you 1.3) and your is missing data elements (which hold string key/values). Demo resx with kay Foo with value bar created in VS2017 you can see at https://pastebin.com/vudy6q6M